# 404 not found on reset password link with Nextjs and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have been sending an email reset password link with dynamic token url from Nodejs backend, but when I click it, my Nextjs frontent shows 404 not found. I really don't know why, since this code works perfectly fine in Reactjs, but I get 404 in Nextjs. Please help!

UpdatePassword.jsx

```
const UpdatePassword = () => {
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [msg, setMsg]= useState('')
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const router = useRouter();
    const {token} = router.query




    const onFinish = async () => {
        const success = () => {
            message.success('You have successfully updated your password, you can login now!', 10);
        };
        try {
            await axios.put('http://localhost:5000/updatePassword', {
                password: password,
                token
            },{withCredentials:true})
            success()
            await router.push('/LoginForm')
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                setMsg(error.response.data.error)
                setError(error.response.status)
                console.log(msg)


            }
        }
    };

    return ()
```

Nodejs backend

```
export const requestPasswordReset = (req, res) => {
   const userId = user.id;
   const token = jwt.sign({userId}, process.env.RESET_PASSWORD_KEY, {expiresIn: '15m'})
   const data = {
                to: email,
                from: process.env.CROFFERS_APP_EMAIL,
                subject: 'Reset Account Password Link',
                template: 'email',
                context: {
                    url: `http://localhost:3000/UpdatePassword/${token}`
                }
            }

            return (
                user.update({token: token}, {where: {token}}).then(() => {
                    transporter.sendMail(data, function (error, body) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log('sendmail:' + error)
                            return res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
                        }
                        return console.log('message sent')
                    })

                }).catch((error) => {
                    return res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
                })

            )
        }).catch((error) => {
            return res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
        })
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'You have not set up an account to send an email or a reset password key for jwt'})
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the file tree of pages folder in nextjs

Comment: Hi! i have uploaded file tree...

Answer (score 0):

It Was a file tree problem iv've had to make directory updatePassword, and then put UpdatePassword.jsx in that folder, also rename UpdatePassword.jsx to [token].jsx